# Analyze Table Syntax Error

Tags: h2, database-tuning

The following sql statement raises a syntax error:

```
analyze table my_table sample_size 0;
```

This is the raised error:

> Syntax error in SQL statement "ANALYZE TABLE MY_TABLE SAMPLE_SIZE[*] 0 "; expected "integer";

The [official documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#analyze) gives the following:

```
ANALYZE [TABLE tableName] [SAMPLE_SIZE rowCountInt]
```

(...)
*The value 0 means all rows are read.*

How to workaround this problem?

**H2 1.4.196**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error results from a bug in the h2 database parsing code. A [fix](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/h2-database/_GhUGTAsC0k/Qr8xYFuvAAAJ) has been sent.

I don't know in which version it willl be available.

Comment: According to the [Change Log](http://h2database.com/html/changelog.html?highlight=fix%20bug%20in%20parsing&search=fix%20bug%20in%20parsing#firstFound), it's fixed in 1.4.197 (2018-03-18)