# how h2 chooses right/wrong index in Join

Tags: performance, join, h2

I had an issues with a [named query in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913418/h2-database-performance-issues-with-named-query), but the issue was that the problem was in H2.

I thought `ANALYZE` was my Solution and would solve my problem. It did locally on my dev machine. On client side it did made it worse.

Scenario:
I have an H2 Database with data version 105. After importing some more data it becomes version 106.

The Table looks like
[image]

The Query (get the rows with given guid, local and highest version):

```
SELECT tdo.TECDOC_GUID as guid, tdo.TECDOC_LOCALE as locale , tdo.TECDOC_VERSION as version, tdo.DATA as data
FROM TECDOC_OBJECTS tdo
LEFT OUTER JOIN TECDOC_OBJECTS tdo1
ON (
    tdo.TECDOC_GUID = tdo1.TECDOC_GUID AND 
    tdo.TECDOC_LOCALE = tdo1.TECDOC_LOCALE AND 
    tdo.TECDOC_VERSION < tdo1.TECDOC_VERSION)
WHERE tdo1.id IS NULL 
AND tdo.TECDOC_GUID in ('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6', 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0')
AND tdo.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de';
```

Before I ran `ANALYZE` command the execution plan (scanCount really low):

```
SELECT
    TDO.TECDOC_GUID AS GUID,
    TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE AS LOCALE,
    TDO.TECDOC_VERSION AS VERSION,
    TDO.DATA AS DATA
FROM PUBLIC.TECDOC_OBJECTS TDO
    /* PUBLIC.IDX_TECDOC_GUID: TECDOC_GUID IN('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6', 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0') */
    /* WHERE (TDO.TECDOC_GUID IN('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6', 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0'))
        AND (TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de')
    */
    /* scanCount: 19 */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.TECDOC_OBJECTS TDO1
    /* PUBLIC.IDX_GUID_LOCALE_VERSION: TECDOC_GUID = TDO.TECDOC_GUID
        AND TECDOC_LOCALE = TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE
        AND TECDOC_VERSION > TDO.TECDOC_VERSION
     */
    ON (TDO.TECDOC_VERSION < TDO1.TECDOC_VERSION)
    AND ((TDO.TECDOC_GUID = TDO1.TECDOC_GUID)
    AND (TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE = TDO1.TECDOC_LOCALE))
    /* scanCount: 4 */
WHERE (TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de')
    AND ((TDO.TECDOC_GUID IN('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6', 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0'))
    AND (TDO1.ID IS NULL))
/*
total: 37
TECDOC_OBJECTS.IDX_GUID_LOCALE_VERSION read: 6 (16%)
TECDOC_OBJECTS.IDX_TECDOC_GUID read: 8 (21%)
TECDOC_OBJECTS.TECDOC_OBJECTS_DATA read: 23 (62%)
*/

SELECT
    TDO.TECDOC_GUID AS GUID,
    TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE AS LOCALE,
    TDO.TECDOC_VERSION AS VERSION,
    TDO.DATA AS DATA
FROM PUBLIC.TECDOC_OBJECTS TDO
    /* PUBLIC.IDX_GUID_LOCALE_VERSION: TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de'
        AND TECDOC_GUID IN('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6', 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0')
     */
    /* WHERE (TDO.TECDOC_GUID IN('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6', 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0'))
        AND (TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de')
    */
    /* scanCount: 287385 */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.TECDOC_OBJECTS TDO1
    /* PUBLIC.IDX_GUID_LOCALE_VERSION: TECDOC_GUID = TDO.TECDOC_GUID
        AND TECDOC_LOCALE = TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE
        AND TECDOC_VERSION > TDO.TECDOC_VERSION
     */
    ON (TDO.TECDOC_VERSION < TDO1.TECDOC_VERSION)
    AND ((TDO.TECDOC_GUID = TDO1.TECDOC_GUID)
    AND (TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE = TDO1.TECDOC_LOCALE))
    /* scanCount: 4 */
WHERE (TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de')
    AND ((TDO.TECDOC_GUID IN('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6', 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0'))
    AND (TDO1.ID IS NULL))
/*
total: 11891
TECDOC_OBJECTS.IDX_GUID_LOCALE_VERSION read: 11884 (99%)
TECDOC_OBJECTS.TECDOC_OBJECTS_DATA read: 7 (0%)
*/
```

After I ran `ANALYZE` command the execution plan (scanCount really high):

```
SELECT
    TDO.TECDOC_GUID AS GUID,
    TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE AS LOCALE,
    TDO.TECDOC_VERSION AS VERSION,
    TDO.DATA AS DATA
FROM PUBLIC.TECDOC_OBJECTS TDO
    /* PUBLIC.IDX_GUID_LOCALE_VERSION: TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de'
        AND TECDOC_GUID IN('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6', 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0')
     */
    /* WHERE (TDO.TECDOC_GUID IN('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6', 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0'))
        AND (TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de')
    */
    /* scanCount: 287385 */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.TECDOC_OBJECTS TDO1
    /* PUBLIC.IDX_GUID_LOCALE_VERSION: TECDOC_GUID = TDO.TECDOC_GUID
        AND TECDOC_LOCALE = TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE
        AND TECDOC_VERSION > TDO.TECDOC_VERSION
     */
    ON (TDO.TECDOC_VERSION < TDO1.TECDOC_VERSION)
    AND ((TDO.TECDOC_GUID = TDO1.TECDOC_GUID)
    AND (TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE = TDO1.TECDOC_LOCALE))
    /* scanCount: 4 */
WHERE (TDO.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de')
    AND ((TDO.TECDOC_GUID IN('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6', 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0'))
    AND (TDO1.ID IS NULL))
/*
total: 11891
TECDOC_OBJECTS.IDX_GUID_LOCALE_VERSION read: 11884 (99%)
TECDOC_OBJECTS.TECDOC_OBJECTS_DATA read: 7 (0%)
*/
```

But on my developer laptop, after `ANALYZE` the query is still fast. Somehow H2 uses the wrong index (as it can only use one index per join, according to documentation).

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` commands? I would like to see the primary key and indexes definitions. Also, do you have self-referential foreign keys that point to the same table (doesn't look like)?

Comment: Hey @TheImpaler, the PK and INDEX can be seen on the image which I provided. Hope this is enough. There are no foreign keys in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what somehow solved the issue is that I used

```
USE INDEX
```

to specify which index it should use.

Here is the Query which uses a certain index by force (or index hint http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html#database_performance_tuning).

```
SELECT tdo.TECDOC_GUID as guid, tdo.TECDOC_LOCALE as locale , tdo.TECDOC_VERSION as version, tdo.DATA as data
FROM TECDOC_OBJECTS tdo USE INDEX (IDX_TECDOC_GUID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN TECDOC_OBJECTS tdo1
ON (
    tdo.TECDOC_GUID = tdo1.TECDOC_GUID AND 
    tdo.TECDOC_LOCALE = tdo1.TECDOC_LOCALE AND 
    tdo.TECDOC_VERSION < tdo1.TECDOC_VERSION)
WHERE tdo1.id IS NULL 
AND tdo.TECDOC_GUID in ('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6', 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0')
AND tdo.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de';
```

This will solve this issue. If you use it with Java and Hibernate, be aware that the parser of H2 does not understand `USE INDEX` in versions before 1.4.194. I had the issue, that with version 1.4.194 some other issues came up. And I deleted some combined Indexes in my table.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not complex. I think the key aspect of it is in the `where` condition.

```
WHERE tdo1.id IS NULL 
  AND tdo.TECDOC_GUID in ('GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6',
    'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0')
  AND tdo.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de';
```

For some reason H2 is using the index the wrong way. I would try to *rephrase* the condition, and see how H2's SQL optimizer works it out.

For example, you can try **option #1**:

```
SELECT
    ... -- columns, FROM, and OUTER JOIN here
  WHERE tdo.TECDOC_GUID = 'GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6'
    AND tdo.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de'
     OR tdo.TECDOC_GUID = 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0'
    AND tdo.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de'
    AND tdo1.id IS NULL
```

Or you can decouple the query in two to make sure it uses the index, as in **option #2**:

```
SELECT
    ... -- columns, FROM, and OUTER JOIN here
  WHERE tdo.TECDOC_GUID = 'GUID-F2F77CE5-D8F5-4286-9A30-8FD500F735F6'
    AND tdo.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de'
    AND tdo1.id IS NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ... -- columns, FROM, and OUTER JOIN here
  WHERE tdo.TECDOC_GUID = 'GUID-41FD28DC-63C0-44D0-B8AE-0FCF7C78CEB0'
    AND tdo.TECDOC_LOCALE = 'de'
    AND tdo1.id IS NULL
```

This way, you are using **equality** only when searching. This one is much simpler to understand to the SQL optimizer. Note the use of `union all` that is cheaper than `union`.